# $\partial S/\partial V = -p/T$? What has gone wrong here?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

Consider two systems, 1 and 2, which can exchange heat and do only the mechanical p-V work. They are isolated from the rest of the world. At equilibrium they have the common pressure, say $\bar p$. Then if we nudge them slightly form equilibrium, then we must have, since isolation, that (I denote by $E$ the internal energies)
\begin{align*}
\text{total heat absorbed} &=(dE_1 - \bar p\;dV_1) + (dE_2 - \bar p\;dV_2)\\
&= d(E_1 + E_2 -\bar p(V_1 + V_2))
\end{align*}
be zero, and hence
$$
E_1 + E_2 = \bar p(V_1 +V_2) + \text{const.}\tag{1}
$$

Now, assuming that the systems are independent,
$$
S_\text{tot}(E_1, E_2, V_1, V_2) = S_1(E_1, V_1)+S(E_2, V_2).\tag{2}
$$

Now, maximizing (2) subject to (1) leads that, at equilibrium,
$$
\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial E_1} = \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E_2}
$$
which we identify as $1/T$, and
$$
\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial V_1} = -\frac{\bar p}{T},
$$
which **contradicts the oft-stated result with the minus sign flipped.**

In hindsight, there must be a minus sign on the RHS of the constraint (1), but I don't see why.

---

**Question:** What exactly has gone awry in the above reasoning of mine?

Comment: @Nephente This is exactly what I show in my question. :)

Comment: @Nephente If you meant the exact mathematical steps that lead to the result that I quote, it is easily obtained by Lagrange multipliers. Btw, can you please tell me the book you you are having? I might get an answer by looking into it.

Comment: How is the total change in energy not simply $\mathrm dE_1 + \mathrm dE_2$?

Comment: @J.Murray This is due to the difference between internal energy and heat. (It is heat which I called "energy".) I've edited. Is it clearer now?

Comment: This is a question of the type "check my calculations" which is not well seen in this site. I think you could easily recast the question in a way that it is more general. Said that, I do not understand what you want to prove. Apparently you are trying to prove the equality of the pressure in the two subsystems under the hypothesis that there is a unique pressure!

Comment: Yes, but via the first law of thermodynamics, the total heat added is $\mathrm dE \color{red}{+} p \mathrm dV$.

Comment: @GiorgioP I am not trying to prove that both the systems reach the same pressure, as it is assumed. I rather try to prove the celebrated result that $\partial S/\partial V = \bar p/T$. But as I try to prove using my arguments I've mentioned, I get the contradictory result. And I hence ask where I made the mistake. 

This is definitely not a "check-my-calculations" kind of question.

Comment: @Atom Oh sorry, "in my book" is a figure of speech meaning "in my opinion". I don't actually have a book on thermodynamics at hand, but the derivation should be presented in any text on the subject.

Comment: @J.Murray You are correct. I am an idiot. :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an actual answer, the error is in the claim that the total heat added $\delta Q$ is given by

$$\delta Q = \mathrm dE - p\mathrm dV$$
The correct expression is $\delta Q = \mathrm dE \color{red}{+}p\mathrm dV$, which solves the problem of the missing sign.

Comment: Right , I was only thinking about $\delta W$.